# Android AVD crashes on launch

Tags: android

When I was starting Android VM from shell commands, the AVD crashes immediately after launch with below error:

```
/Users/allanjiang/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/emulator -avd Nexus_5X_API_28_x86 -netdelay none -netspeed full
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::length_error: vector
Abort trap: 6
```

Everything runs fine a day ago, and start hitting this issue starting today. Please help if you have seen this issue.

OS is macOS 10.14.3

Comment: Did you try resetting the vm instance? Sometimes weird things happen and resetting will resolve them.

Comment: Hi @jackz314 how do you reset the VM instance? I have tried both restart the VM and restart my computer but nothing worked...

Comment: Go to AVD manager, select your VM instance, then select more and click wipe data. If that doesn't work, just delete it and reinstall a new one.

Comment: @jackz314 wiping data works! Thanks for help! If you want to add an answer, I'll accept it asap.

Comment: Glad I could help, just posted as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes weird things happen and resetting the VM will resolve them.

Go to AVD manager, select your VM instance, then select more and click wipe data. If that doesn't work, just delete it and reinstall a new one.